# Why is the redirection of loop output dependent on the filename?

Tags: shell, files, io-redirection, wildcards

I have two files: `a.csv` and `b.csv`:

```
echo $'a_header\na1' > a.csv
echo $'b_header\nb1' > b.csv
```

Now I want to remove the first line from each, and concatenate them.

```
for file in `ls *.csv`; do cat $file | tail -n +2 | cat; done
```

However, when I redirect the output of the previous command to a file, I get different results depending on the name of the output file.

```
for file in `ls *.csv`; do cat $file | tail -n +2 | cat; done > result
for file in `ls *.csv`; do cat $file | tail -n +2 | cat; done > result.csv
```

---

```
cat result
a1
b1
```

---

```
cat result.csv
a1
b1
b1
```

Comment: `result.csv` is itself a part of the list created by `*.csv`.

Comment: But the file does not exist when ls *.csv is evaluated.

Comment: `result.csv` file is created (empty) before `ls *.csv` is evaluated.

Comment: But if it is empty, why is the content of 'result.csv' different from 'result'?

Comment: That's a [useless use of `ls`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls).  You mean `for file in *.csv; do`...

Comment: Your `cat`s are obviously also [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html).  The command you are trying to perform is better written `tail -q -n +2 *.csv >result; mv result result.csv` (where using a file name which does not match your wildcard avoids the wildcard problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the following command:

```
command > file
```

The standard output (fd 1) of the command `command` is redirected to the file `file`. If the file does not exist, it is created. A command normally redirects its command output to the file descriptor 1 (stdout).

When using an expression as above (where the output is redirected to a file), the file must exist before the ouput stream starts. Therefore `bash` creates the file (empty) and connects is to stdout of `command`, which then start to write on that file descriptor.

This is handled by the shell. The command does not know whether it writes to a anonymous pipe or a file.

---

Given this command:

```
for file in `ls *.csv`; do cat $file | tail -n +2 | cat; done > result.csv
```

What here happens, is the file `result.csv` is created empty. Then the `for` loop runs trough every file whose ending is `csv` (including `result.csv`). The files are processed `a.csv`, then `b.csv` and at least `result.csv`. The second line of `result.csv` in then `b1`. That's why you have 2 lines in the result file.

Comment: Not part of the question proper, but you really, really should get rid of the useless `cat`s here.

Comment: @tripleee True **and** get rid of parsing `ls` of course.